# Centos 7.7 KVM virtualization - two NICs, two separate bridges, cannot access NIC from outside

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I searched for answer and tried different things but couldn't solve the problem, I really need help.

There are LAN and DMZ networks:
DMZ 192.168.0.0/24
LAN 192.168.1.0/24

I have Intel server with two NICs, one NIC is connected to LAN 192.168.1.0/24 and another is connected to DMZ 192.168.2.0/24. I installed Centos 7.7 and configured two bridge networks. One NIC is added to one bridge and another NIC is added to second bridge. Firewall and selinux are disabled.

My intention is KVM virtualization, let's say I want to create 3 VMs in LAN using bridge br1 and 3 VMs in DMZ using bridge br0.

Here is my config:

cat ***ifcfg-br0***
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.10
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
DNS1=1.2.3.4

cat ***ifcfg-br1***
DEVICE=br1
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=1.2.3.4

cat ***ifcfg-enp1s0f0***
NAME=enp1s0f0
HWADDR=25:15:17:d8:45:d0
UUID=1c63e92f-c0ad-4b2f-84d0-c44c085fe729
DEVICE=enp1s0f0
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DNS1=1.2.3.4

cat ***ifcfg-enp1s0f1***
NAME=enp1s0f1
HWADDR=25:15:17:d8:45:d1
UUID=a8138523-624b-47de-a2dc-d28a711a00bc
DEVICE=enp1s0f1
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DNS1=1.2.3.4

When there was br0 only everything worked as expected but as soon as I added br1 I cannot ping br0 properly.

From DMZ network I can ping br0 but not br1 interface and from LAN network I can ping br1 interface and not br0. I tried tcpdump but it seems like both bridge interfaces receiving packages and I am only pinging one br.

Individual guest VMs seems to work fine, only accessing host from outside is problem.

Please help, maybe something is wrong with my routing table:
***ip route***
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br1
192.168.1.0/24 dev br1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.10
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10

Thanks

Comment: Having two default gateways probably isn't going to be helping anything, for starters.

Comment: I just figured it out, I was distracted with KVM and bridge interfaces, problem is that I need two routing tables and two gateways, each for every interface. I found out that I can archive this on Centos using iproute2 program. Do you know any better solution?